# In python-sql interfacing how do I use string parameters properly?

Tags: python, sql

I am writing a function to retrieve an item from a table 'MenuEntree' but there is apparently a syntax error in the cur.execute() argument.

```
import mysql.connector as mc
con = mc.connect(user = 'root',host = 'localhost', password = 'something',database = 'something')
cur = con.cursor()

def getItem(ID,course):
    currentItem = ''
    cur.execute("select Item from %s where ID = (%s)",("Menu" + course,ID))
    currentItem = cur.fetchone()
    return currentItem
```

This is the table:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dy5Ty.png)

Error message:

Exception has occurred: ProgrammingError
1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '} where ID = (%s)' at line 1
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '} where ID = (%s)' at line 1

Tried messing around with the brackets and parameters but nothing worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use string parameters properly in Python SQL interfacing, you should use placeholders `(%s)` in the SQL query string and pass the values as a tuple as the second argument to the `cur.execute()` method. However, you cannot use placeholders for table or column names in SQL queries. Instead, you can use string formatting to safely insert the table name into the query.

```
import mysql.connector as mc

con = mc.connect(user='root', host='localhost', password='something', database='something')
cur = con.cursor()

def getItem(ID, course):
    currentItem = ''
    table_name = "Menu" + course
    query = "SELECT Item FROM {} WHERE ID = %s".format(table_name)
    cur.execute(query, (ID,)) # passing placeholder in tuple format
    currentItem = cur.fetchone()
    return currentItem
```